How to mark a parameter with an attribute in a dynamically created Lambda Expression?
Doing the following, I obtain a simple lambda to sum two integers:
using System.Linq.Expressions;

var xParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "x");
var yParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "y");
var sum = Expression.Add(xParam, yParam);
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<int, int, int>>(sum, [xParam, yParam]);
var func = lambda.Compile();
var result = func(1, 2);

Which is equivalent to having this:
var func = (x, y) => x + y;
var result = func(1, 2);

Now, how can I mark the parameters of the lambda with attributes?
This comes in handy when - for example - you want to dynamically generate the endpoints of a minimal API application and you need to mark the parameters with [FromServices]. Can I generate a lambda like this using expression trees?
([FromServices] ISender sender, [FromBody] LoginDto body, CancellationToken ct) =>
    sender.Send(new LoginQuery(body), ct)

I can't find anything, neither on Expression.Parameter(), nor any other factory methods of the Expression class.
But a solution like this would allow me to collapse the endpoints/controller layer with the CQRS one avoiding a lot of boilerplate (since the former in not doing much).

Metadata like [FromServices] are static, and are applied to types.  For instance FromServicesAttribute has [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter | AttributeTargets.Property, ...)]. I would be happy to be proven wrong, but I can't imagine how you would do that with expressions, which create instances of delegates but not types.  Maybe you would need to use TypeBuilder?

For TypeBuilder, see e.g. Programmatically add an attribute to a method or parameter.  My impression is that this class is not easy to use though.

This is currently not possible. Expression trees cannot contain attributes. The compiler explicitly tells you this when you try to compile something like this:
Expression<Func<int, int>> e = ([Foo] x) => x;

public class FooAttribute: Attribute { }

The error message says:

CS8972: A lambda expression with attributes cannot be converted to an expression tree

I can't find anything in the LDMs that explains why this isn't supported, but in theory, expression trees can totally include information about attributes - it'd just be another tree node.
